# Error opening eclipse from android ADT bundle download

Tags: java, android, adt

I downloaded the ADT bundle for windows in the android developers website. I'm expecting that once I extracted them on my C: it will just run smoothly. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error

[image]

Any ideas on what's causing this? Already downloaded java from oracle website. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25.

Edit:
For those asking the version of my OS. Here it is.

[image]

So I'm sure I downloaded the right version of the ADT.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have downloaded wrong version of Adt. Are you sure that it is suitable for your pc? Is your computer 64-bit?

Comment: Yes. I can guarantee that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's the 32-bit or 64-bit version. If that doesn't work, re-install java. The jvm.cfg file is an internal file and should not really be touched, but it seems Google might have a custom one for the emulator or something. If that still doesn't work, open SDK Manager and install everything they have. Otherwise I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the real problem but I uninstall JRE and install again ..Now its perfectly working .